# Why is this post marked as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

The following software related post has been marked as off-topic:
[How can I set up en passant in Popeye engine?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/26553/how-can-i-set-up-en-passant-in-popeye-engine)

The "specific"? reason given is that "the question does not appear to be about chess within the scope defined in the help center". This tells me no more, but at least I get to look at the scope, and see that software is only marked as one of the various grey areas in chess.stackexchange scope.

Therefore, any vote for putting on-hold of a grey area matter should reasonably include an indication of why the question was seen by the individual moderator as inappropriate. Otherwise we learn nothing from the whole process.

More broadly, one of the big success areas of stackexchange is to give detailed answers to pointed questions how to use technology, and it seems odd to exclude this usage in the chess area, which uses software tools so heavily.

So: reflection rather than reflex please.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it is a grey area. The line in the Help Center that I used for guidance was this -

> Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other
>   chess software are welcome.

Your question wasn't about programming an engine or programming other chess software so I added my vote to close to two others. I don't have strong feelings on the subject and so would certainly not block any attempt to reopen. If you feel strongly (and since you have  gone as far as raising the subject here you probably do) then vote to reopen.

Note also this line in the Help Center:

> Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure
>   are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for
>   reopening

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw the remark about programming questions, but see no implication there for questions about software *use*. I will do what you recommend